# Laravel 5.2 Cache Increment and Expiration

Tags: php, laravel, caching

So when I set a value to be cached and I want to increment the value it resets the expiration time?

To test it I've set a value and expiration to 1 minute. Then I used increment every second until 1 minute and it didn't expire.

How can I increment without resetting the expiration time?

```
$app->cache->put($requestCache . '_Minute', 0, 1); // value 0, expire in 1 minute
$app->cache->increment($requestCache . '_Minute'); // doing this resets the 1 minute expire time
```

Comment: Naturally `increment()` uses `put()` and therefore resets the duration. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to add requests to cache and expire them. Basically for limiting requests. I found a solution to add an array to the cache instead with the value and time it should expire.

Comment: @Kristjan Can you post your solution here please? I'm facing same trouble using L5.2.

Answer (score 1):

If cache driver is Redis. The code is work

```
$app->cache->put($key, $app->cache->increment($key), 1)
```

Comment: This is not recommended since it defeats the purpose of 'increment'. The operation is now no longer atomic and in high concurrency situations, some increments might go lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  ["predis/predis"](https://github.com/predis/predis) package

```
  $storage=Redis::connection();
  $storage->zIncrBy("",1,$key)
```